$1^\alpha+2^\alpha+3^\alpha+\cdots+n^\alpha$
Let $\alpha>0$ and $m$ be a positive integers, use Euler's summation formula we can prove that there exists a constant $C$ such that
$$    \sum_{k=1}^nn^\alpha=\frac{n^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}+\frac{n^\alpha}{2}+{\color{red}C}
  +\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-2k+2)n^{\alpha-2k+1}$$
$$+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-2m)}{(2m+1)!}
  \int_1^nB_{2m+1}(x-[x])\cdot x^{\alpha-2m-1}dx. $$
$$=\frac{n^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}+\frac{n^\alpha}{2}+{\color{red}{C_1}}
  +\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-2k+2)n^{\alpha-2k+1}+O(n^{\alpha-2m-1}).$$
Here the two constants $C$ and $C_1$ maybe different.
My question is: can we prove that the constant $C_1$ equals to $\zeta(-\alpha)$? Here $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann zeta function.

Let $f(x)$ be a smooth function over $(0,+\infty)$, by Euler–Maclaurin formula, we have that
$$f(1)+f(2)+\cdots+f(n)=F(n)+C+\frac{f(n)}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}f^{(2k-1)}(n)$$
$$-\int_n^\infty\frac{B_{2m+1}(\{x\})}{(2m+1)!}f^{(2m+1)}(x)dx,$$
where
$$C=\frac{f(1)}{2}-\left(F(1)+\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}f^{(2k-1)}(1)\right)$$
$$+\int_1^\infty\frac{B_{2m+1}(\{x\})}{(2m+1)!}f^{(2m+1)}(x)dx..$$
Here $F(x)$ is a primitive function of $f(x)$. Let $f(x)=x^\alpha$ and $F(x)=\frac{x^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}$, then
$$C=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\alpha+1}-\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-2k+2)$$
$$+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-2m)}{(2m+1)!}
  \int_1^\infty B_{2m+1}(x-[x])\cdot x^{\alpha-2m-1}dx.$$
For $\Re s>1$, Let $\zeta(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{n^s}$ be the Riemann zeta function. Similarly, by Euler-Maclaurin formula, we have that
$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}+\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{s(s+1)\cdots(s+2k-2)}{(2k)!}B_{2k}-
  \frac{s(s+1)\cdots(s+2m)}{(2m+1)!}\int_1^\infty\frac{B_{2m+1}(x-[x])}{x^{s+2m+1}}dx$$
and use this formula we can extend the definition of $\zeta(s)$ to the half plane $\Re s>-2m$. Take $s=-\alpha$, we have that
$$\zeta(-\alpha)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\alpha+1}-\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-2k+2)$$
$$+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-2m)}{(2m+1)!}
  \int_1^\infty\frac{B_{2m+1}(x-[x])}{x^{-\alpha+2m+1}}dx.$$
Hence
$$C=\zeta(-\alpha)$$
and thus
$$1^\alpha+2^\alpha+\cdots+n^\alpha=\frac{n^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}+\frac{n^\alpha}{2}+\zeta(-\alpha)
  +\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-2k+2)n^{\alpha-2k+1}+O(n^{\alpha-2m-1})~(\alpha<2m).$$
